# Making a restaurant reservation in french

Tags: expressions

I've been using Duolingo, but I realize that I have no idea how to make a restaurant reservation in French.

Could people suggest useful expressions with translations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly simple, you can piece it from different lessons in Duolingo:

*Bonjour, je voudrais réserver une table pour (deux/trois/etc) personnes s'il vous plaît...*
Translation: I would like to book a table for (two/three/etc) people please.

*...C'est pour (ce soir/demain après-midi) à __ heures*.
Translation: It is for (tonight/tomorrow afternoon at __ o'clock).

Answer (score 0):

You can find many websites or video to have examples or vocabulary.
I found this one if you want.

[Typical French Restaurant Vocabulary: How to Order in Paris](https://www.tripsavvy.com/paris-restaurant-vocabulary-1618379)